# Build APK in release mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, apk, release

I am having trouble building apk in release mode. No matter what I do I always get BuildConfig.DEBUG flag set to true.

I tried the following

1. set android:debuggable="false" in manifest file.
2. Used Export option(by right clicking on project in eclipse) to create signed apk.
3. Use Android Tools->Export unsigned apk to create apk.

But when I decompiled the code using dex2jar and JD I saw BuildConfig.DEBUG set to true.

Also, when I used the following code in app to check debug flag, I always get result 'true'(in both debug and release mode)

```
Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(BuildConfig.DEBUG), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

Please tell me the correct method to build the apk in release mode and to protect code from decompiling.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a bug with ADT, which I am still able to reproduce
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940

As a workaround you may use your own boolean to toggle (true/false) logging as this:

```
public final class AppConfig {
   public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
}

// and later use it as
if (AppConfig.DEBUG) {
   Log.d(TAG, "lorem ipsum..");
}
```